# Is there a way to run watch on webpack and grunt running in a sequence

Tags: webpack, gruntjs, watch, grunt-contrib-watch

I am running webpack and grunt in a sequence. Weback compiles my JavaScript code, and grunt deploys that code to a local apache server. Here's my npm script:

package.json:

```
...
"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack && grunt"
}
```

I have scenario where I need to run watch on both. Is there a way to do that?

I have already tried using `grunt-webpack` for webpack but unfortunately it is not working properly with my `webpack.config`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [webpack-shell-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-shell-plugin):

```
plugins: [
  new WebpackShellPlugin({
    onBuildEnd: ['gulp']
  })
]
```

Comment: It's not solving my problem. I need to complete my webpack build first before running grunt because grunt deploys the code generated by webpack.

Comment: @SachinSingh Use [webpack-shell-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-shell-plugin).

Comment: Webpack shell plugin didn't help me either as webpack watch was not working with clean webpack plugin, but the idea of using a shell plugin in grunt worked for me. Thanks!